# Bundle Requests to a sailsjs app

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Using Sailsjs I am building a web api to consume from an Angularjs front-end and an android app. Since there will be many api calls, even for a view, I was thinking of bundling the requests and  have the server respond with a complex json object to reduce overhead.

The request object will have the format:

```
[
  {
      url : "api/call/some/thing"
  },
  {
      url : "api/call/some/other/thing"
  }
]
```

And the response object will be something like :

```
[
  {
    url : "api/call/some/thing",
    status : 200,
    res : {** data goes here **}
  },
  {
    url : "api/call/some/other/thing",
    status : 200,
    res : {** data goes here **}
  }
]
```

My question is how to call other controllers' actions using the urls I have and I there is a library or a module that handles this kind of functionality